# Get related entities from CRMService

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4

I'm trying to build a sharepoint BCS connector that grabs data from CRM4. I have it fetching normal attributes from the "contact" entitiy, but I'm not seeing how to retrieve things like related contacts, custom entities or meetings/appointments, etc.

I have read through these:

[how to get related entities in dynamics CRM 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578186/how-to-get-related-entities-in-dynamics-crm-2011)

[Retrieve a list of entites from CRM 2011, each with all of their related entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139455/retrieve-a-list-of-entites-from-crm-2011-each-with-all-of-their-related-entitie)

[Microsoft CRM, how do I get all the members of a list using CrmService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853500/microsoft-crm-how-do-i-get-all-the-members-of-a-list-using-crmservice)

But I can't seem to see any reference to what I am doing. I'm using the normal CRMService web service. I am using the normal request:

```
var contacts = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
```

That only gets me access to the basic attributes, unless I am missing something. If a contact has a few entities related to it (other contacts/meetings), can I grab that from the same query? Or does this require another hit to another entity?

Answer (score 1):

From what I know (and remember from CRM 4), you have to query each entity independently. On the other hand, you can filter on what you want:

```
var query = new QueryExpression
            {
                EntityName = "new_typedecontrat",
                ColumnSet = new ColumnSet { AllColumns = true },
                Criteria = new FilterExpression
                {
                    FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And
                }
            };
            var expression2 = new ConditionExpression("new_typedecontratid",   ConditionOperator.Equal, campaign.New_TypedecontratId.Id);

            query.Criteria.Conditions.Add(expression2);

            EntityCollection entitys = CRM.Instance.RetrieveMultiple(query);



try
            {
                using (var serviceProxy1 = new OrganizationServiceProxy(organizationUri, homeRealmUri, credentials, null))
                {
                    // This statement is required to enable early-bound type support.
                    serviceProxy1.ServiceConfiguration.CurrentServiceEndpoint.Behaviors.Add(new ProxyTypesBehavior());
                    serviceProxy1.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
                    CRMService = serviceProxy1;

                    return CRMService.RetrieveMultiple(query);
                }
            }
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: I was hoping for another way to do this, only because this can be a time consuming query (the CRM4 Api is pretty slow from what I've seen). I know there is a related view on the DB, i'm wondering if this is exposed to the API in a simpler way.

Comment: Yes, when you query the service, you actually query on views (Contact is a view, for example). This may give you more info related to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009359/performing-complex-query-with-dynamics-crm-4-0